# Why is EndExecuteNonQuery() Needed?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asynchronous

The documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca56w9se.aspx) states that

> developers must call the
>   EndExecuteNonQuery method to finish
>   the operation.

I have not been able to find a good reason as to why this is, or what the results of not calling `EndExecuteNonQuery` are.

Any insight as to what will happen if it is not called? I don't want to block on it, is there a way for it to be automatically called in an `AsyncCallback`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do things like:

- update parameter values (out/return)
- check for exceptions (error codes in the TDS stream - constraint violation etc)
- release any objects/data buffered as part of the above etc

So yes: do it

Answer (score 1):

By definition, all such asynchronous calls cannot be made in a using block to make sure the connection is closed. As such, calling EndExecutexxx is necessary.

Looking at the code in reflector, we can see trace of closing the connection in `EndExecuteNonQuery`:

```
 SqlDataReader reader = this.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader();
 if (reader != null)
 {
      reader.Close();
 }
```