# EndExecuteNonQuery, What is it, What does it do and How to use it?

Tags: c#, mysql, try-catch

I'm inserting datas in a mysql database through a C# application, I would like to know if the insertion was or  not successful and searching on the internet I read something about "EndExecuteNonQuery", but it wasn't explaining nothing about the way should use it. I have no ideia the way I can use it even why should I use it.

```
try
        {
            cepescola = txtcepescola.Text + txtcepescola1.Text;
            num_escola = int.Parse(txtnumescola.Text);
            cnpj = txtcnpj.Text + txtcnpj2.Text;
            telefoneescola = txtddd.Text + txttel.Text;
            inserte.Append("Insert into estabelecimento ( Nome,CEP,Endereco,Numero,Bairro,UF,CNPJ,Telefone)");
            inserte.Append(" values ");
            inserte.Append("( '" + txtnomeescola.Text + "','" + cep + "','" + txtenderecoescola.Text + "','" + num_escola + "',");
            inserte.Append(" '" + txtbairroescola.Text + "','" + cbxufescola.Text + "','" + cnpj + "','" + telefoneescola + "')");
            conexao.ExecutaComando(inserte.ToString());
            groupBox2.Enabled = false;
            btnestabelecimento.Visible = false;
            btnlogin.Visible = true;
            txtlogin.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Dados digitados em formato incorreto.", "Erro de Dados", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            groupBox2.Enabled = true;
            btnestabelecimento.Visible = true;
            btnlogin.Visible = false;
            txtlogin.Focus();

        }
```

Where can I use it in this case and what should I change? 
Obs: At "Conexão.ExecutaComando(insertd.ToString());" it's a class i've created to execute commands.

And just one more thing, i used Try and Catch in case of exception but I want to abort the connection if the user write, for example, words where he must write numbers. My applicaion is finding the mistakes but it's inserting anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[`EndExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.endexecutenonquery.aspx) is used i conjunction with [`BeginExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutenonquery.aspx) to execute a command on the database asynchronously. I suggest you get more comfortable solving your issues before looking into running your queries asynchronously.

On the subject of your need to validate user inputs, I suggest 2 things. The first is to remove the risk of SQL injection attacks by using parameters in your commands. For example, instead of using the following (reduced for brevity):

```
var sql = "insert into estabelecimento (Nome) values ('" + txtnomeescola.Text + "')";
```

You should use the following:

```
var sql = "insert into estabelecimento (Nome) values (@nomeescola)";
//assume cmd is a SqlCommand instance
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeescola", txtnomeescola.Text);
```

Secondly, if you need to perform validation on the inputs to your query then you should do that **before** executing the command. You already validate your `num_escola` parameter by parsing it into an `int` which will stop it being a string. You should do the same with your other numeric parameters, and maybe consider using [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160181/why-is-endexecutenonquery-needed) will be useful for you

> **Quote:**
> This will do things like:
>
> 1. update parameter values (out/return)
> 2. check for exceptions (error codes in the TDS stream - constraint violation etc)
> 3. release any objects/data buffered as part of the above etc

Comment: This is correct and at the same time probably useless for the OP. (Actually, "TDS stream" is an SQL Server detail that as I understand it does not even apply to MySQL.)